Размер программы для ядра GPU
Программирование в среде CUDA. (6 лекций)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oqebkc0NO_8
Я посмотрел все 6 лекций, так и не узнал где в памяти GPU хранится сама программа для адра GPU и какое ограничение на ее размер. Везде бала речь только о памяти данных. Данные пересылаются туда, данные пересылаются суда. А сама программа адра не пересылается в GPU? Об этом 0 информации.
Поделитесь кто-нибудь зниниями.

Надо сказать, что лекции 10-летней давности.

Программа в память устройства естественно попадает в каком-то виде для исполнения. Как и куда именно - это секрет. Nvidia публикует руководство по программированию своих устройств в терминах работы некой виртуальной машины NVPTX, чьи спецификации не проясняют многих деталей аппаратной реализации, в т.ч. механизм доставки инструкций. Ограничения на размер на практике нет. Руководство 10 версии заявляло 512м инструкций на одну kernel, что намного больше того, что требуется в реальности. А в 12 версии вообще убрали сведения о такого рода ограничении.
Посмотреть на скомпилированное ядро и оценить его размер можно посредством бинарных утилит CUDA

Поверхностный анализ запросов в гугл nvidia gpu instructions cache size и nvidia gpu instructions memory latency позволяет предположить, что команды gpu во время исполнения хранятся в памяти GPU (не system RAM) и выбираются через как минимум L1 и L2 caches (также упоминается L3 cache)
